# How to use Intent in kotlin fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent

[image: one]

As you see `Intent` is red and I can't make it fix **any idea?**

Comment: Have you  import the intent class?

Comment: @AbdulWaheed .........yes

Comment: use getActivity() instend of "this"
Intent(getActivity(),splash2::class.java)

Answer (score 2):

make use of `requireContext()` instead of `this` inside fragments

```
val intent = Intent (requireContext(), foo::class.java)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using it in `Fragment`,so use `context` instead of `this`
context?.let{ nonNullContext ->
val intent = Intent(nonNullContext, splash2::class.java)
}

Comment: Don't do it like this, this is bad and leads to crashing, forcing optional context to be non nullable, context can be null in case if activity is destroyed, wrap it with context null check if so, or with context?.let {...